# What is the use of the $\epsilon$ term in this back-propagation equation?

Tags: machine-learning, backpropagation, notation, learning-rate

I am currently looking at different documents to understand back-propagation, mainly at [this document](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/%7Emeeden/cs81/s10/BackPropDeriv.pdf). Now, on page 3, there is the $\epsilon$ symbol involved:

$$
\Delta w_{k j}=\varepsilon \overbrace{\left(t_{k}-a_{k}\right) a_{k}\left(1-a_{k}\right)}^{\delta_{k}} a_{j}
$$

While I understand the main part of the equation, I don't understand the $\epsilon$ factor. Searching for the meaning of the $\epsilon$ in math, it means (for example) an error value to be minimized, but why should I multiply with the error (it is denoted as E anyways).

Shouldn't the $\epsilon$  be the learning rate in this equation? I think that would be what makes sense, because we want to calculate by how much we want to adjust the weight, and since we calculate the gradient, I think the only thing that's missing is the multiplication with the learning rate. The thing is, isn't the learning rate usually denoted with the $\alpha$?